# How to disable certain Android sound alerts?

Tags: motorola-droid, audio, 2.1-eclair

I have a Motorola Droid phone running Android 2.1. Many times per day my phone alerts me with a sound. It is not a new email or SMS or disconnection from the 3G network. I suspect it may alerting me about new WiFi networks that come in or out of range (I live in a big apartment building with dozens of networks around). That's only my suspicion as there is no indication on the screen about what triggered the sound alert.

I looked in Settings/Sounds but I don't see any category for such alerts.

And just to be clear: I want to find out how to disable the sound only for some alerts. I do not want to mute all of them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same annoying signal like a vibrating buzz. I want to get rid of it. All tasks are closed and it still does it.

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe because you ave a Google Talk session opened : It's the same for me, for day, I've looking for what "ring" like that and don't display any informations...

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you have SMS delivery receipts turned on - an alert is sounded when the recipient gets yr message.